# pick and choose from two nested lists by a pattern using Python

Tags: python, list

I have two nested lists (list of lists) and one nested list of True/False (pattern) that I want to use to pick and choose items from two input lists to create a final list.

```
inputListTrue = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
inputListFalse = [[a,a,a],[b,b,b],[c,c,c]]
pattern = [[True, False, True],[True, True, True],[False, False, True]]

finalDesiredList = [[1,a,1],[2,2,2],[c,c,3]]
```

What is the most efficient way to create a definition that would work on any depth of nested lists....`[[[],[]],[]]` etc. I was looking for something really flexible unlike my initial thought of just iterating:

```
for i, j, k in zip(pattern, inputListTrue , inputListFalse ):
    for l,m,n in zip(i,j,k):
        if l:
            finalDesiredList .append(m)
        else:
            finalDesiredList .append(n)
```

This is only good for a list of lists and not for list of list of list etc. Ideas?

Comment: Perhaps [``filter()``](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) would help.

Comment: Is the elements within lists always equal?

Comment: I don't understand your requirement for 'any depth of nested lists'.  Could you give a full example? Perhaps [flattening the list of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) is something to look at.

Comment: @Kasra no, they will be a mix of things. Anywhere from strings to integers and maybe even other object types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive method to do this for arbitrary nested sequences

```
def choose(first, second, value):
    if hasattr(first, '__iter__'):
        return [choose(i,j,k) for i,j,k in zip(first, second, value)]
    else:
        return first if value else second
```

Example

```
>>> inputListTrue = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
>>> inputListFalse = [['a','a','a'],['b','b','b'],['c','c','c']]
>>> pattern = [[True, False, True],[True, True, True],[False, False, True]]
>>> choose(inputListTrue, inputListFalse, pattern)
[[1, 'a', 1], [2, 2, 2], ['c', 'c', 3]]
```

This is assuming the sequences all have have the same dimensions.

Comment: OP is looking for a general way for arrays with more dimensions!

Comment: @Cyber Yes, I was looking for a more dimensional solution. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 1):

As a more general way you can use a recursion function :

```
def filt(pattern, inputListTrue , inputListFalse ,finalDesiredList=[]) :
      for i, j, k in zip(pattern, inputListTrue , inputListFalse ):
          temp=[]
          for l,m,n in zip(i,j,k):

              if isinstance (l,list):
                   return filt(i,j,k)
              else :
                 if l:
                      temp .append(m)
                 else :
                      temp .append(n)
          finalDesiredList.append(temp)
      return finalDesiredList



inputListTrue = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
inputListFalse = [['a','a','a'],['b','b','b'],['c','c','c']]
pattern = [[True, False, True],[True, True, True],[False, False, True]]

print filt(pattern, inputListTrue , inputListFalse)
[[1, 'a', 1], [2, 2, 2], ['c', 'c', 3]]
```

Comment: yes, this works but i will still need to add a check for whether its a flat list before i go into two subsequent "for loops". Otherwise it will throw an error on a flat list.

Comment: @konrad You didn't mentioned about that! i'll update the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
def filtFlat(pattern, inputListTrue, inputListFalse):
    result = []
    for i, j, k in zip(pattern, inputListTrue, inputListFalse):
        if i == False:
            result.append(k)
        else:
            result.append(j)
   return result

def filt(pattern, inputListTrue , inputListFalse ) :
    finalDesiredList=[]
    for i, j, k in zip(pattern, inputListTrue , inputListFalse ):
        temp=[]
        for l,m,n in zip(i,j,k):
            if isinstance (l,list):
                return filt(i,j,k)
            else:
                if l:
                    temp.append(m)
                else:
                    temp.append(n)
        finalDesiredList.append(temp)
    return finalDesiredList
```

I can always use the two definitions and do a check for a flat list:

```
if any(isinstance(item, list) for item in pattern):
```